# Work Flow Support multiple Scenario

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I am building a base workflow will support around 25 Customer 
all customers they matches with one basic workflow and each one has little different request lets say one customer wanna send email and another one don't wanna send email 
What I am thinking to make

```
  1- make one workflow and in the different requirement I will make switch to check who is   
   the user then switch each user to his requirements 
    (Advantages)this way powerful in maintenance and if there is any common requirements 
                easy to add   
    (Disadvantages) if The customer number increase and be like 100 and each is different 
                  and we expect to have 100 user using the workflow but with the Different 
                  little requirements 
  2- make Differnt workflow for each customer which meaning I will have a 100 workflow 
     in the future and in declaration instantiate the object from the specific workflow 
     which related to the Current user
     (Advantages) each workflow is separate 
     (Disadvantages) - hard to add simple feature this meaning write the same thing 100   
                       time so this is not Professional
```

so What I need ?? 
I wanna know if those only the ways I have to use in this situation or I missing another technique

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to break out your workflow into smaller parts, each which do a specific thing. You could organize a layout like the following, to be able to support multiple variations of the inbound request.

```
Customer1-Activity.xaml
 - Common-Activity1.xaml
 - Common-Activity2.xaml

Customer2-Activity.xaml   
 - Common-Activity1.xaml
 - Common-Activity2.xaml
```

For any new customers you have, you only need to create a root XAML activity, with each having the slight changes required for your incoming request parameters.

### Option #2: Pass in a dictionary to your activity

Thought of a better idea, where you could have your workflow have a `Dictionary<string, object>` type be an input argument. The dictionary can contain the parameter/argument set that was given to your workflow. Your workflow could then query for the parameter set to initialize itself with that info.

Comment: but lets say we will have a 100 customer this meaning I will have a 100 xaml main files just for the customer

plus the little  small Activity 
I am looking for another solution 
If it be possible

Comment: I thought of another possible way, using a dictionary as your workflow's input argument.